# BLDC motor A2212 wont spin using STM3202 evaluationboard

Tags: stm32, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am running into a problem with the STSPIN3202 evaluationboard. I cant get my BLDC motor A2212 930KV 15T with sinusoidel BEMF to spin.
I have tried 6 step sensorless and FOC sensorless. In case of 6 step the motor keeps buzzing stationary so it is wat i think a startup problem. With FOC it just gives beep and nothing more(I didnt forget to change the jumpers according to https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um2278-getting-started-with-the-stevalspin3202-evaluation-board-advanced-bldc-controller-with-embedded-stm32-mcu-stmicroelectronics.pdf ).

For both methods I took some example code from the MC workbench and changed some motorparameters and the Vbus voltage.
V-bus voltage is 11V.
For the Motorparameters I couldnt find a datasheet so I had to determine them.

[image]

The pole pairs parameter is determined by spinning the motor with my hand. Full rotation counted (12 steps so 6 pairs).

The board is powered with 11V.

The Rs and Ls are measured with a multimeter and a LCR meter.

The BEMF constant I calculated: 930KV, 930rpm/V = 0.0011V/rpm 1.1V/krpm

1.1/(2 * squareroot(2)) = 0.38 Vrms/krpm.

luukredstone_3-1708266563089.png

On the startup parameters I didnt change much just default from the example BullRunning Motor 1700kV.

[image]

Drive settings are also all default

[image]
Speed sensing is also sensorless

I have tried both MC WB(5.4.8 and the 6.2.1) and what I find remarkable is that in the 5.4.8 version the speed monitor wont work it just freezes. By the way I am new to BLDC motors.

If someone could tell me what I am doing wrong, I would appreciated that.